# Button inside react-native-webview

Tags: webview, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to implement functionality which allows user to press on an image, that is part of an html which is opened with webview in react-native and then the image will be zoomed. What would be the best way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Yes, the image is inside the webview, however the webview is part of react-native and the functionality needed should be handled from the mobile side, so it is a question related to react-native framework

Comment: But the image is not a react-native component, it is a html component, because is inside a webview which is rendering a html. If it was a react-native component it would be like ```<Image/>``` inside your .js/.ts file and etc...

Comment: Im sorry, i dont see how your comments are helping or providing information. I fully understand what you are trying to say, however the html is inside a webview component, provided by react-native. So the question is, is there a way to implement onPress on that image from the html

Comment: The main function of a webview in react native is just to show a html. What is written in the html it does not have nothing with the react-native side, you understood better now? So, you must implement a onPress in the html, not in the react-native. When you implement in the html and you render this html in the react-native-webview, it will work.

Comment: That is not just not true, sorry. There are multiple methods provided to the html from the native side of the application that allows for different interactions with the webview, then just rendering the html. :)

Comment: Yes, I know that it has some methods that connect the html to the native side. But, the interaction with a Image doesn't have this "connection".

Answer (score 2):

This property [injectedjavascript](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#injectedjavascript) should help you. You can inject your own `js code`, with this prop you can programmatically, add the `onclick` function to your image.